# How to convert the time to a c string in c?

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

I wanna to write something to a .txt file in .c file, but required to name that file with the current timestamp as the postfix, just like filename_2010_08_19_20_30. So I have to define the filename char array first and process the filename by myself?Assign the character one by one?

Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a function called `strftime` that exists for the express purpose of writing a time value into a human-readable string. Documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

An example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE* file;
   char filename[128];
   time_t now;
   struct tm tm_now;

   now = time(NULL);
   localtime_r(&now, &tm_now);

   strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "filename_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M.txt", &tm_now);

   file = fopen(filename, "w");

   fprintf(file, "Hello, World!\n");

   fclose(file);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  time_t timet;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [32];

  time (&timet);
  timeinfo = localtime(&timet);

  strftime(buffer,32,"_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M",timeinfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the strftime function:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/