# How to print unsigned int value as a time string in C

Tags: c, datetime, type-conversion

I need to print this value as a time string to Mon 16-Aug-2010 06:24 format or something similar.

```
unsigned int t = 1281920090;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522480/how-to-convert-the-time-to-a-c-string-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the functions [**gmtime**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/) and [**asctime**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/asctime/) as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
        time_t timestamp = 1281920090;
        printf("%s", asctime(gmtime(&timestamp)));
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc a.c && ./a.out
Mon Aug 16 00:54:50 2010
```

Answer (score 2):

That's actually a `time_t` not an unsigned int.

You can use `ctime` to generate a simple string in a similar format (or a combination of `asctime` and `localtime` or `gmtime`) or you can use `strftime` to specify the exact format you want.

Comment: isnt time_t just 'unsigned int' typedef'ed in time.h ?